# Transparent Bridge from Wifi to Ethernet using Raspbian

Tags: networking

### Bridging

There's a lot of information available on bridging for various configurations, some of which is targeted at RPi, others which is available for the general Debian distribution.  I've wasted about a day digging through all of it, and still haven't found a satisfactory answer.

Is there a sane way to do this?

#### Clean State

Let's start from a clean slate and state the expectations:

- I have an existing router providing wired and WPA2 access to an internet connection
- I have a Raspberry Pi with a wireless adapter (8192cu driver, RTL8188CUS device)

  - It is running the latest Raspbian Wheezy
  - Its firmware is up-to-date per `rpi-update`
- Neither `iptables` nor `ebtables` have any rules
- `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

Here's the simple-and-easy `/etc/network/interfaces` which works for basic connectivity.

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

wpa-ssid   "YourWifiSSID"
wpa-psk    "YourWpaPassphrase"
```

#### Requirements

Now let's add some requirements.

- I have a device which has an ethernet port, which I want to connect to the network
- I want to connect this device via ethernet to the RPi

  - It should get address via DHCP from the router
  - It should be on the same subnet as all other devices

This rules out NAT (via `iptables`) and per-device MAC spoofing (via `ebtables`).

#### Examples

The closest thing that I've seen is a [Gist on Github](https://gist.github.com/alandipert/5146588) (though there are [others](http://www.eb-home.eu/blog/Using-a-Raspberry-as-a-network-bridge) like it)

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports wlan0 eth0
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_waitport 0

wpa-iface  wlan0
wpa-bridge br0
wpa-ssid   "YourWifiSSID"
wpa-psk    "YourWpaPassphrase"
```

Rebooting after setting this configuration, no DHCP address is pulled by `br0`.  According to `iwconfig`, `wlan0` is associated with the base station.

Setting `br0` to a `static` address gives it an IP, but there's no connectivity (cannot `ping` the gateway, even though `ip route` shows the correct route).

Comment: http://blog.chaucery.com/2013/02/raspberry-pi-wireless-bridge.html

Answer (score 0):

A guess - did you try a crossover ethernet cable?

Also you dont need ip on the bridge to connect device behind it. Use tcpdump on bridge and eth to understand where the packets are lost

Comment: You should not need a crossover cable since the turn of the century, that said I have no idea if the Pi and the posters device implement it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable (Automatic crossover)

Comment: A crossover would only matter if the ethernet-attached device was lacking connectivity.  In this case, the RPi itself lacks connectivity, while it should have connectivity even if the Ethernet is disconnected.

`Printer --> Ethernet --> RPi --> Wireless --> Router --> Internet`

Comment: Zach, you are correct of course. I answered assuming wifi is connected and bridge and device behind it has an issue